# Touchpad not working after kernel upgrade

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, gentoo, touchpad

I am on Gentoo currently. I decided today to give the 5.8rc-7 kernel a go. I configured and compiled it. After reboot, however, my touchpad was not working. So I configured and compiled again, this time enabling all the features relating to 'mice', 'touchpad' or 'trackpad'. Still it didn't work.

Do I have to change anything else?

Or is there another solution?

Comment: Did you copy the `.config` file from the previous kernel sources, where the touchpad worked?

Comment: @BlueManCZ Nope. Forgot to back up. : |

Comment: It will be in the `/usr/src/linux-<old-version>/.config`

Comment: Yeah there is. So .config of different versions will be compatible? Because the 5.8 make menuconfig looked a little different.

Comment: I think the problem is with the kernel. It didn't work with the previous config (also noticed that sound too was not working, alsamixer showed no devices). Even ```genkernel all``` did not work. Booted to 5.4.48 from grub menu. It worked. Going to try the zen-sources now!

Comment: No, you have to adapt this old config for the new kernel. Explained [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Upgrade#Update_the_.config_file).

Comment: With the correct kernel configuration, your touchpad should be working in the console already (`sys-libs/gpm` should work).
Now, for X11 (I'll assume you're not running wayland...), depending on what kernel version you had installed previously, you may have to re-install your driver (which links against the kernel if I am not mistaken): `x11-drivers/xf86-input-synaptics` or `x11-drivers/xf86-input-evdev`. Also check your X logs (usually at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`) for obvious errors and see https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Synaptics for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Try the answers given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307447/network-not-working-updating-to-kernel-5-8-ubuntu-20-04). That helped me a lot